# How to retrieve POST parameters from AuthorizeAttribute in Web Api .Net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an authentication method using a token for me Web Api .Net project, so I am overriding some methods like this:

```
public class Authorizetest: System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
           if(Authorize(actionContext))
        {
            return;
        }
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);  
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    private bool Authorize(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {         
        try
        {                           
            var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            HttpRequestBase request = context.Request;              
            string token = request.Params["Token"];
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the decorator `[Authorizetest]` on this way:

```
[Authorizetest]
    public class DoActionController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpPost]
            public Display DoSomething(Parameter param)
            {
                //do something
                return display;
            }
    }
```

But the `request.Params` is returning `null` however in the `DoSomething` method I get the value from `Parameter`.

I also have tried something like: (based on [this page](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2015/05/08/token-based-authentication-for-web-service-apis-in-c-mvc-net/))

```
    HttpRequestBase request = actionContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
    string token = request.Params["Token"];
```

, but it's not possible to retrieve any value sent through the POST method.

I am using JQuery to send the data

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/DoSomething',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "Token": "xxxxxxxxx"}),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                },
                fail:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

How can I retrieve the data sent to `DoSomething` in the `Authorizetest class`?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question. It's not very clear.

Comment: @Difster, Thanks, I've changed the question a little bit I hope it's clearer

Comment: You've already got the data that is being sent. Why would you need to retrieve what you already sent? It's in your `data` variable.

Comment: @Jamo that is because what you seek is in the body of the request, not `Params`. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Tokens should be send in the HEADER of the request and then extracted by the Authorize Attribute if the intention is to use it for auth. Reading the request body before the model binder has a chance to populate models can have negative effects.

Comment: OR send it in the query string

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks! I was doing wrong, so I need to send the token in the HEADER instead of the BODY.

Comment: @Jamo Header or query string will work. I would suggest using the Authorization header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auth Tokens should be sent in the header of the request and then extracted by the Authorize Attribute if the intention is to use it for authorization. Reading the request body before the model binder has a chance to populate models can have negative effects.

```
var token = "xxxxxxxxx";
$.ajax({    
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/DoSomething',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "SomeProperty": "SomeValue"}),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        /* Authorization header */
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);        
    },
    success: function (data) {
    },
    fail:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Then access it on the server

```
public class Authorizetest : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute {
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        if (Authorize(actionContext)) {
            return;
        }
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    private bool Authorize(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        try {
            var auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (auth != null) {
                var scheme = auth.Scheme; //Should be Token, otherwise fail
                var token = auth.Parameter;
                //Validate your token and set your principal
                IPrincipal user = GetUser(token);
                if (user != null) {
                    SetPrincipal(user);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private IPrincipal GetUser(string token) {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //Put your implementation here
    }

    private void SetPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principal) {
        if (principal != null) {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null) {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for! +1!